# OpenLayers 3 map.getLayers() failing

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to build a layer switcher and I am at the point where I need to get ALL layers for the map so I am using...

```
// array with layers:
var layers = map.getLayers().getArray();
```

however I am receiving the error message "map.getLayers is not a function"

I am using OL3 3.16...any help is greatly appreciated!!

here is my map ...

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="map" style="padding-top: 0px; width: 100vw; height: 90vh;z-index: 0"></div>
```

here is where I instantiate the map...

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'sat' })
            })
            //,layer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 0,

        })
    });
```

Comment: An `ol.Map` [does have the getLayers() method](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getLayers), so the only reasonable conclusion is that your `map` variable is not really an `ol.Map`. Impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: right do you have a div with id map?

Comment: I've edited the question to include creating the map, i figured that was a given. :)

Comment: The problem must still be somewhere in the code you've not included. After declaring the map as above in the JS console on http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html doing `map.getLayers().getArray()` returns a valid result. Your problem is not with OpenLayers itself, but with the JS code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct...since I am using AngularJS I needed to create a map object in the main angularjs controller and propigate that through my code.  After I did this I had access to getLayers() in my other Angular controllers.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the down voting?  This is going to be very helpful to developers using AngularJS and OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AngularJS I needed to create a map object in the controller where I am creating the map...

```
angular.module('webMapAPI.LoadMap', [
   ...load objects
])
    .factory('WebMapLoad', WebMapLoadFactory);
WebMapLoadFactory.$inject = ['$parse', '$state', '$stateParams','$q'];
function WebMapLoadFactory($parse, $state, $stateParams,$q) {
    function WebMapLoad() {
        this.map = new ol.Map({});
    }
```

Then in the "LoadMap" function of the same controller...(just the way I decided to do it)...assign to the $scope object map...

```
WebMapLoad.prototype.LoadMap = function () {
var control = this; (in angular sometimes you need to pull the main controllers $scope object in)

control.map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'sat' })
            })
            //,layer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 0,

        })
    });
}
```

Once I did this I had access to the map in every controller I injected "WebMapLoad" into.

*Disclaimer the code above is pseudo code and has not been tested.

Answer (score 0):

An additional bit of functionality to go with the solution is gaining access to the layers and being able to manipulate their properties.  This is how I did it, which seems to be pretty clean... (WebMapLoad is an AngularJS module that I use to create my map)

```
$scope.setVisibility = function (layer) {
                    angular.forEach(WebMapLoad.map.getLayers().getArray(), function (Field, key) {
                        if(layer.get('id') == Field.get('id'))
                        {
                            if (layer.U.visible) {
                                Field.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            else {
                                Field.setVisible(true);
                            }

                        }

                    }


                )}
```